# Bring one application in front of another in Windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, qt, windows-10

I have two separate processes running with Qt, where I'm in need of being able to bring one in front of the other. They both communicate with each other so you'd think it wouldn't be a big problem. However Windows 10 is very strict on this specifically. All I manage to do is make the window I want to bring in front blink orange in the windows toolbar.

Code I'm trying to use so far:

Class A (currently active):

```
AllowSetForegroundWindow(ASFW_ANY);
```

Class B (The one I want to bring in front):

```
#ifdef WIN32
    if(hWnd)
    {
        SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
        SetActiveWindow(hWnd);
        BringWindowToTop(hWnd);
    }
#endif
```

The hWnd is gotten earlier (While Class B was the active window) with:

```
hWnd = GetActiveWindow();
```

Have I misunderstood something? Why is this still not working?

Comment: This Qt workaround has worked for me at least under Windows 7 & 8.1
Maybe it will still work under Windows 10.      

this->setWindowState((this->windowState() & ~Qt::WindowMinimized) | Qt::WindowActive);     

    this->setVisible(false);    

    this->setVisible(true);    

    this->setFocus();    

BringWindowToTop((HWND)this->winId());    


_this_ is subclass of QWidget

Comment: Does `AllowSetForegroundWindow` return success, and is there user input happening between calling `AllowSetForegroundWindow` and trying to activate process B (because the permission given to process B [expires as soon as the user generates more input](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632668(v=vs.85).aspx))?

Comment: @GSerg I was not aware of AllowSetForegroundWindow expiring on user input. There was indeed input in between the calls. This fixed the issue :) Thank you!

Comment: @AcerExtensa Your code seems to do the same thing as mine. It works as long as AllowSetForegroundWindow is set correctly.

Comment: @AcerExtensa I'll add that ((HWND)this->winId() is a much more elegant way of getting the hwnd compared to GetActiveWindow(), as the latter only works when the window is currently active, while the former works at any time.

Comment: GetActiveWindow() is wrong, it can never return a window owned by another process.  You probably meant GetForegroundWindow()

Comment: @HansPassant I believe `GetActiveWindow` is [correct](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20081006-00/?p=20643/) because the `hwnd` of the in-process active window it returns is then used in an attempt to bring that window to foreground.

Comment: @HansPassant It was correct in this instance as it was being used while it was still the active window, ie before moving on to the other process. GetForegroundWindow would probably work as well. But like I said, ((HWND)this->winId() seems the most elegant solution as it will work at any time for that process, and not just in specific situations.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I set the Qt/Windows widget on top at all times?

Having faced quite a few issues like the above the following solution is working for me:

```
void widgetToTop(QWidget* widget)
{
    bool wasMax = widget->isMaximized();
    bool wasMin = widget->isMinimized();
    HWND h = (HWND)widget->winId();
    if (wasMax || wasMin)
    {
        ::ShowWindow(h, SW_SHOW);
        ::ShowWindow(h, wasMax ? SW_MAXIMIZE : SW_RESTORE);
        ::SetForegroundWindow(h);
    }
    else
    {
        ::ShowWindow(h, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
        ::SetForegroundWindow(h);
    }
}
```

This of course can be reworked with pure Win32 API.

P.S. Maybe the solution is not exactly "on top of another" but likely it is sufficient.

Comment: This will work if both windows are part of the same process. If they're separate processes, as was my case, then it will only work if the foreground window specifically gives permission for another process to jump to the foreground in its stead, and (as was my mistake) this permission only lasts until the next user input. I believe this was introduced in windows 10 to stop potentially spammy popups.